# Do not show notification if certain activity is being displayed. Execute this activity's method instead

Tags: android, notifications, google-cloud-messaging, intentservice, android-context

I have downloaded GCM example code from https://code.google.com/p/gcm/ and It works fine.

I have added two activities and now my project contais the following files:

- GcmBroadcastReceiver (extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver) (original)
- GcmIntentService (extends IntentService) (original)
- MainActivity
- ActivityListView

In the original code when the gcm message arrives, the notification is always shown but now I would like the notification only be shown when the ActivityListView activity is not being displayed.

If the app is displaying ActivityListView, the notification should not be shown and an ActivityListView method should be executed instead.

I mean I need some code like this:

```
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

    if(ActivityListView is being displayed){
        ActivityListView.mymethod(extras);
    }
    else{
        sendNotification("Received: " + extras.toString());
    }
}
```

Now GcmIntentService looks like:

```
public class GcmIntentService extends IntentService {
.....

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
    String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);
    if (!extras.isEmpty()) {  // has effect of unparcelling Bundle
        .......
            sendNotification("Received: " + extras.toString());
        }
    }
    GcmBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
}
```

And GcmBroadcastReceiver looks like:

```
public class GcmBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
            GcmIntentService.class.getName());
    startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
    setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Activity**

You need first to know if your activity is displayed or not. That is not supported natively by Android.
Use a simple boolean set to true in onResume() and false in onPause() should du the trick.

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

  private boolean visible;

  @Override
  public void onResume() {
    visible = true;
  }

  @Override
  public void onPause() {
    visible = false;
  }

  public boolean isVisible() {
    return visible;
  }

}
```

**ActivityListView**

Depending on your architecture, you can do many things.

I would probably create a custom broadcast intentfilter and register this like so in your Activity:

```
registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {
  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (isVisible() {
      // ...
    }
    else {
      // notify
    }
  }
}, new IntentFilter("CUSTOM_BROADCAST_INTENT_FILTER"));
```

**GcmBroadcastReceiver**

That CUSTOM_BROADCAST_INTENT_FILTER broadcast would be launched from your GsmBroadcastReceiver.

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent("CUSTOM_BROADCAST_INTENT_FILTER"));
```

Comment: What happens with all the actual GsmBroadcastReceiver code? and GcmIntentService? Could you explain the broadcast stuff a little more please? I have edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

A pretty easy way to do this is to get the current task from the ActivityManager and simply compare class names:

```
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

    ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) this.getSystemService( ACTIVITY_SERVICE );
    // Get info from the currently active task
    List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> taskInfo = am.getRunningTasks( 1 );
    String activityName = taskInfo.get( 0 ).topActivity.getClassName();
    if(activityName.equals( ActivityListView.class.getName() ))
    {
        // Execute that special method from ActivityListView
        ActivityListView.mymethod(extras);
    }
    else
    {
        // Show the notification
        sendNotification("Received: " + extras.toString());
    }
}
```

In your `AndroidManifest.xml` you will need the permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
```

Comment: And how to execute the activity method?

Comment: According to your question, you want the evaluation to take place in the onHandleIntent() method. I've updated the code a bit. About executing the method: just call it?